# Using React Router to control independent components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I am new to React/Redux and I'm struggling with controlling my app layout with React Router (What I am doing maybe beyond the realms of React Router). I have the following code setup:

INDEX.JS

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
  <Router history={ browserHistory } routes={ routes } />
</Provider>
, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

APP.JS

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TopNavigation />
        <SideNavigation />
        <Stage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

SIDENAVIGATION.JS

```
render() {
  const openSideNavDrawer = classNames({
    'side-navigation-drawer': true,
    'open': this.state.sideNavIsOpen
  });

  return (
    <nav className="side-navigation">
      <ul onMouseOver={ this.openSideNavDrawer.bind( this ) } >
        <li>
          <Link to="/project">1</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/pages">2</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/blocks">3</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/reorder">4</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/download">5</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div className={ openSideNavDrawer } onMouseOut={ this.closeSideNavDrawer.bind( this ) } >
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

ROUTER.JS

```
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={ App }>
    <Route component={ SideNavigation }>
      <Route path="/project" component={ Project } />
      <Route path="/pages" component={ Pages } />
      <Route path="/blocks" component={ Blocks } />
      <Route path="/reorder" component={ Reorder } />
      <Route path="/download" component={ Download } />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

WIREFRAME WITH EXPLANATION

[image: Overview of my requirements]

So far I have only attempted to wire the side navigation, I am receiving no errors but the routing is not working.

Please can anyone explain if:

a/ This is even possible with React Router?

b/ If it is possible what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found any resolution to this? I'm struggling with complex layout using router as well. Would be curious if you found any direction.

Comment: I didn't find a resolution using only React Router. For the side navigation components I have ended up with all my components rendered on the screen and I animate/show them using `this.state`.